# Visual Studio 2012 and IVsSingleFileGenerator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-sdk

I'm porting my existing extension written for VS2010 SDK to VS2012 SDK and there seem to be some changes involving IVsSingleFileGenerator.

Basically, I'm creating a .VSIX with:

1. Project Templates
2. Item Templates
3. A **custom tool** (implementing IVsSingleFileGenerator)

Did someone made a similar thing for **VS2012** and got some code examples?

Comment: The visual studio SDK has tons of samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was different from VSSDK 10.0:

- If you follow the VSSDK10 sample on single code generator, one has to mark ComVisible(true) all the hierarchy (cf: [Why is my Visual Studio 2010 custom tool not being found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098681/why-is-my-visual-studio-2010-custom-tool-not-being-found)).
- The CodeGeneratorRegistrationAttribute is now part of the Shell 11.